# installing magento store back up

Tags: php, error, installation

I Have got an online version of my Magento store, and now i have got the files (SQL dump, and the root files)

So, i am trying to localhost my site, so i have a new blank version of Magento (not installed) and i add MySql database to phpmyadmin (imports not errors) then i run Magento installation, point it to the database i created, but nothing is import, it just stays as the stock Magento webpage, and the back-end also has no data, but something is happening because the favicon has changed to that of my website.. Do i need to import my app/design theme? as well as my /media folder?

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong; its a new version of Magento that is being pointed to my database, but no data is showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the sql dump already uploaded to the database you will online need to unpack the dump with the files, correct the database settings in `app/etc/local.xml` and change the base urls in the `core_config_data` table to your local settings to get it to work.

No need to do a clean install of Magento in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Couldn't find an answer for this anywhere on the internet lol!